# DecimalFormat Problem throws a StackOverFlowError?

Tags: java, android

I have a edit text. i want to enter the decimal values in it.

that is when i have enter a first number. it should be like this: `.01`

then i have enter a second number. it should be like this: `.12`

then for third one. it should be like this: `1.23`

it will go like this.... how to implement this scenario in the **Android Platform**. Any Idea?

Edit:

I have tried this.But i got the StackOverFlowError when i am appending the string into the EditText. i have posted my code below:

```
amount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                try {
                    if (s.length() == 1) {
                        Float f = Float.parseFloat(s.toString()) / 100;
                        System.out.println(String.valueOf(f));
                        amount.setText("");
                        amount.append(String.valueOf(f));//getting stackoverflow error here
                    } else if (s.length() > 1) {
                        String str = s.toString().replace(".", "");
                        Float f = Float.parseFloat(str) / 100;
                        System.out.println(String.valueOf(f));
                        amount.setText("");
                        amount.append(String.valueOf(f));
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: @DroidBase : which technology in java are you using? Andriod? Swing? JSP/HTML? or any other? more explanation needed in your question.

Comment: I am using the edittext in Android Platform.

Comment: @DroidBase: you should mention it in your question. at least you should add an android tag in your question.

Comment: @Harry Joy: I have done that.

Comment: Please dont tell me that you are appending the input text of the EditText and setting that text back to Edittext. [That shit is recursive](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&source=hp&biw=1298&bih=707&q=recursion&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&fp=1&cad=b). It will definitely be the [the cause of this](http://www.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @Reno: Okay. Is there anyway to achieve this scneario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look, you are implementing a TextChangedKListener for an element, in which you are changing the element text.

So, in this lines

```
amount.setText("");
amount.append(String.valueOf(f))
```

your TextWatcher implementation is being called (as you can see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#afterTextChanged%28android.text.Editable%29)).

As you can see on the second link, the API doc for the `afterTextChanged` method, warns you about the risk of getting into infinite loops:

> be careful not to get yourself into an infinite loop, because any changes you make will cause this method to be called again recursively

The self [afterTextChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#afterTextChanged%28android.text.Editable%29) description, on the TextWatcher API doc, recommends a workaround for handling with this:

> You are not told where the change took
>   place because other afterTextChanged()
>   methods may already have made other
>   changes and invalidated the offsets.
>   But if you need to know here, ***you can
>   use setSpan(Object, int, int, int) in
>   onTextChanged(CharSequence, int, int,
>   int) to mark your place and then look
>   up from here where the span ended up***.

Comment: @Thomas: Is there anyway to achieve this scneario?

Comment: @DroidBase: edited to add the API recommended strategy. I don't really know how well would this work, as I haven't yet needed to do something like this